# How many maximum shared memory keys can be created using ftok() in linux?

Tags: c, linux, memory, kernel, ipc

I am creating share memory keys using `ftok()`. I want to create 500 share memory keys.As per man page of `ftok()` it is mentioned that low order 8 bits are significant.

Does it mean that we can only generate 256 maximum share memory keys?
If yes, Then how to generate more than 256 keys?

Because in argument `ftok()` is defined to take int argument for `proj_id`:-

```
key_t ftok(const char *pathname, int proj_id);
```

So it should generate `2^0` to `2^31` unique keys with same path name.

Comment: What is the *real* problem you try to solve by creating so many keys? Why do you need to create so many? Please read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Hi dude,I Want to create one parent and 500 child processes and want to create a share memory between them.

Comment: Unless you're on a very high-end system that seems extremely excessive. Again, what is the *real* problem you need to solve? Why do you need so many processes? Perhaps you should ask about the original problem you need to solve, and we could provide you with a better solution than swamping your system with processes?

Comment: I am working in a DVB Media stream company and I want to take 500 channels from satellite and modify them to insert Advertisement and send them to customers.For that I have taken one Process to monitor all the channels status.

Comment: Why not use the posix shared memory API instead of the old SYSV one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number of keys that can be created by `ftok` is not limited by the integer argument to `ftok`. It depends on both the integer argument and the path argument also. Even if only the low-order 8-bits of `int` argument are significant, the number of paths are in theory innumerable.

The key returned by `ftok` is of the type `key_t` which is `__S32_TYPE` and this is an `int`. So this can go from `2^0 to 2^31` on an implementation where `int` has 4 bytes.

As per the man page for [ftok](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/ftok.html):

> The `ftok()` function shall return the same key value for all paths that name the same file, when called with the same id value, **and return different key values when called with different id values or with paths that name different files existing on the same file system at the same time**. It is unspecified whether `ftok()` shall return the same key value when called again after the file named by path is removed and recreated with the same name.

But as others have pointed out in the comments, it is not advisable to create so many processes.